# What are the requirements for progress?

Tags: twilight-imperium

I've lost galactic progress map for Twilight Imperium 2 edition. So now we can only play till one person obviously dominates all the others, which takes a lot of time. Each progress step requirements are not written in the rulebook.

If anyone has this edition of the game, can you please tell me, what the requirements are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Galactic Progression Chart](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/159338/twilight-imperium-2nd-edition): If you view the original size it should be big enough to read, and maybe even print off as a replacement.